# Batch - Command to format a String

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am finding it bit difficult to get a solution to my problem. I want to format a string/line which i read from File A and then save it into file B recursively.

**Content of file A.dlg in path "c:\test folder\Akash\form1\A.dlg:**

```
[FFF][3][PLACE Holder][LOCATION][DESCRIPTION][TABS][FILE1.xml,FILE2.xml][FILE3.xml][FILE4.xml][][][1][Arial]
```

After formatting the line, the output should be written into a file (temp.txt)

```
[FFF][3][PLACE Holder][LOCATION][DESCRIPTION][TABS][Akash\form1\FILE1.xml,Akash\form1\FILE2.xml][Akash\form1\FILE3.xml][Akash\form1\FILE4.xml][][][1][Arial]
```

My Current Command to Recursively run through all the folder and find files with .dlg extension and read it content is

```
for /r "..\Akash\" %%F in (*.dlg) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%%F"') do @echo %%a[] >> temp.txt
)
```

But this just copies the line doesnt format it. Can you guys help me

Comment: Your filenames with FILE?.xml are not constants and are not the same, is that right?

Comment: Yes file names would change its not constant.

Comment: Do you want two levels of folders or all child folders from `c:\test folder\one\two\three\four\a.dlg` as in `one\two\three\four\file.xml`

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion with GNU [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed "s/FILE/Akash\\form1\\FILE/g" A.dlg
```

Answer (score 1):

using variable replace ?

```
C:\temp>set test=[FFF][3][PLACE Holder][LOCATION][DESCRIPTION][TABS][FILE1.xml,F
ILE2.xml][FILE3.xml][FILE4.xml][][][1][Arial]

C:\temp>echo %test:FILE=Akash\form1\FILE%
[FFF][3][PLACE Holder][LOCATION][DESCRIPTION][TABS][Akash\form1\FILE1.xml,Aka
form1\FILE2.xml][Akash\form1\FILE3.xml][Akash\form1\FILE4.xml][][][1][Arial]
```

Comment: You should add `FILE` to your replace string.

Comment: so does %test:FILE=Akash\form1\FILE% search the string for "FILE" and then repalce it with "Akash\form1\file". forgive me if this is a silly question :)

Comment: yes it will make the remplacement in the variable. see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Comment: let me try out this... my files names changes from folder to folder. If folder 1 has ABC.xml, folder 2 would have GDF.xml.

Comment: You can't use that so. Can you use powershell script?